# Haipad M701 using /nand directory when I request external storage

Tags: android

I have an Android app which by preference uses external storage if available to store various files but will use internal storage if external storage is unavailable.

I've extended Application and maintain a static File for the app's working directory as follows...

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    protected static File myFilesDir = null;
    protected static Helper myHelper = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        myHelper = new Helper(this);
        if (myHelper.CanWriteExtStorage()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - myHelper.CanWriteExtStorage() returned TRUE");
            myFilesDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - myHelper.CanWriteExtStorage() returned FALSE");
            myFilesDir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
        }
        myFilesDir.mkdirs();

        if (!myFilesDir.equals(null)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() - myFilesDir: " + myFilesDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

The app is currently being beta-tested by some people I'm in direct contact with and one guy commented that he thought I was supposed to be using the SD card if available but he could see from logcat the app was using `/nand/Android/data...` I asked what /nand referenced and he said it is internal memory on his pad/tablet device.

The code the Helper class uses to check for external storage is as follows...

```
protected boolean CanWriteExtStorage() {
    boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
            mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
    return mExternalStorageWriteable;
}
```

...but the relevant log output is as follows...

```
D/com.mycompany.myapp(3844): onCreate() - myHelper.CanWriteExtStorage() returned TRUE
D/com.mycompant.myapp(3844): onCreate() - myFilesDir: /nand/Android/data/com.company.myapp/files
```

So, the question is why, when I'm able to test that the external storage state shows it is mounted, would `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` return a path to what appears to be internal storage?

Should I be testing for something other than `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED` or is there just something strange about this device or Android version (he is running v2.1).

In the long run it possible doesn't matter but I'm concerned my logic is incorrect for certain devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

> Note: don't be confused by the word
>   "external" here. This directory can
>   better be thought as media/shared
>   storage. It is a filesystem that can
>   hold a relatively large amount of data
>   and that is shared across all
>   applications (does not enforce
>   permissions). Traditionally this is an
>   SD card, but it may also be
>   implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the
>   protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.
>   In devices with multiple "external"
>   storage directories (such as both
>   secure app storage and mountable
>   shared storage), this directory
>   represents the "primary" external
>   storage that the user will interact
>   with.

I have not personally seen a case but there is no requirement that getExternalStorageDirectory returns the memory card.  You are doing the correct thing by treating the returned directory as shared storage as it was an intentional decision by the device manufacturer.

Comment: I had actually read that before but din't properly pick-up on "may also be implemented as built-in storage in a device that is distinct from the protected internal storage" (or didn't quite understand). So he has internal, 'nand' and SD card storage and the mfrs decided 'nand' is preferred to SD card...hmmm. Not sure I approve of their decision as it is causing some minor issues. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Mister I kind of figured you might not like it :) Unfortunately, I couldn't locate a method for requesting one type of the other (nand vs. sdcard)

Comment: I agree there only seems to be those two methods with no parameters for choice. I'm going to give him a custom apk which will explicitly target the SD card I know he has. It will at least help explain if using nand is the root of the issues he's having or not. Thanks again.